# how can I split the elements of a list of binary numbers?

Tags: python, list, binary

I'm trying to split the elements of a list of binary numbers as follows :

`bin_list=['000101111000','011110111011']`

Expected result:
`bin_list=[[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1]]`

I think that would be a list of a list of integers what I'm trying to get??
I tried searching a similar procedure and I've tried some but I can't get it right
pls help

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with nesting list comprehensions:

```
>>> bin_list = ['000101111000','011110111011']
>>> [[int(n) for n in ns] for ns in bin_list]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as follows:

```
result = [list(map(int, k)) for k in bin_list]
```

`list(map(int, k))` should basically split the string into a list with individual characters cast as integers, as elements.

Comment: thank you very much it works fine!  I just turned characters into integers

Comment: edited my post, to convert each character into an int, rather than str. Please do consider upvoting, if the post benefits you.

Comment: Why use `list(map())` over a list comprehension?

Comment: cleaner, and cuz python has a `map` function